# Is it possible in Pony ORM to add extra attributes to the intermediate table of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: attributes, many-to-many, ponyorm

In Pony ORM, it is possible to ‘automatically’ create a many-to-many relationship. For example, [from the documentation](https://docs.ponyorm.com/relationships.html#many-to-many-relationship) (for version 0.6, emphasis mine):

> In order to create many-to-many relationship you need to define both
>   ends of the relationship as Set attributes:
>
> ```python
> class Product(db.Entity):
>     tags = Set("Tag")
>
> class Tag(db.Entity):
>     products = Set(Product)
> ```
>
> In order to implement this relationship in the database, Pony will
>   create an **intermediate table**. This is a well known solution which
>   allows you to have many-to-many relationships in relational databases.

Is it possible to create an extra attribute (column) in the automatically created intermediate table, so not just foreign keys to ‘Product’ and ‘Tag’, but, e.g., also a timestamp?

If yes, how?

If not, I guess I'll have to create the intermediate table explicitly. Can I in that case still use the nice `Set`-attribute definition (perhaps to the intermediate table, indicating the attribute of interest)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently it is necessary to define explicit entity, like this:

```python
class Product(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    tags = Set("ProductTag")

class Tag(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str, unique=True)
    products = Set("ProductTag")

class ProductTag(db.Entity):
    product = Required(Product)
    tag = Required(Tag)
    PrimaryKey(product, tag)
    timestamp = Required(datetime, default=datetime.now)
```

Pony does not support virtual `Set` attributes like `through` in Django, but we plan to add them in the future. Right now you need to work with intermediate table explicitly.

**Adding a tag to a product**

```python
p1 = Product[1]
tag1 = Tag.get(name='smartphones')

p1.tags.create(tag=tag1)
# or:
ProductTag(product=p1, tag=tag1)
```

**Removing a tag from a product:**

```python
ProductTag[p1, tag1].delete()
```

**Checking if a product has a specific tag:**

```python
ProductTag.get(product=p1, tag=tag1) is not None
```

Also, Pony support the concept of [attribute lifting](https://docs.ponyorm.com/working_with_relationships.html#attribute-lifting). That means that in Pony any collection attribute has all attributes of its items. The value of a such collection attribute is a collection of all values for individual items. For example, in order to get all tags for specific product, you can write:

```python
p1.tags.tag
```

The `p1.tags` expression returns a collection of `ProductTag` items. Each `ProductTag` object has `tag` property which points to a specific tag object. So `p1.tags.tag` returns a collection of all `Tag` objects linked with a specific `Product` object.

It is possible to use attribute lifting inside queries. For example, in order to found all products with the tag `smartphones` you can write the following query:

```python
select(p for p in Product if 'smartphones' in p.tags.tag.name)
```

Here, `p.tags` is a colection of `ProductTag` objects, `p.tags.tag` is a collection of `Tag` objects, and `p.tags.tag.name` is a collection of tag names. The query above is a syntactic sugar for the following query:

```python
select(p for p in Product if 'smartphones' in select(item.tag.name for item in p.tags))
```

Also, the query can be rewritten as:

```python
select(pt.product for pt in ProductTag if pt.tag.name == 'smartphones')
```